# How do I put a dll into my project - visual studio C# 2010

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I need to put a dll file into my project, my notes say simply drag the dll into the toolbox but it doesn't seem to be working.

How do i do this?

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you accept the answer?

Comment: @Hi-Angel because he hasn't been here since 2011

Answer (score 39):

You use the "References" item in the Solution Explorer to add a reference to it; Right-click and choose to Add Reference. There is an option there to select the DLL file.

When you do this, by default the DLL is copied and included in the project's output, which is what you usually want for a .NET Assembly, anyway.

Which reminds me to ask to make sure; Are you talking about a .NET Assembly DLL here? Things could be quite different if you mean a native code DLL.

Comment: Does VS copy the dll to the project so other developers also get the dll?

Answer (score 3):

Put the DLL into the root of your ASP.NET project, then make a regular .NET reference to it.  Once you click "Add Reference..." you'll get to the .NET assemblies tab in the reference dialog.  Then you click "Browse" which should open up the root directory of the project.  In there you'll find the DLL you want to use, select it and ok out of everything.  Visual Studio will then copy the DLL into the bin directory for you and the code that uses that assembly will then work.

`<%@RegisterAssembly="(DLL Name)"Namespace="(Namespace from Object Browser)"TagPrefix="(Any Prefix)" %>`